# Can I move my iTunes library to a network drive?

Tags: itunes, network, music

The question title pretty much says it all. I'd like to be able to free up space on my iMac G5's hard drive. I had considered upgrading the drive, but moving it off the Mac seems like it'd be a better option.

If I'm able to do this, might it be possible that other non-Mac computers could make use of the MP3s on the server? I'd love to, for example, be able to access the library when the Mac isn't on, particularly from my ChromeOS laptop and Win7 netbook. (I can post a separate question to SuperUser about that part of the issue.)

The mac is a G5 iMac, the drive is a LaCie 2TB drive connected to an AirPort hub via USB.

What would I need to do to get this to work? What about protected AACs from the Apple Store? (I still have a few of those, but most of my iTunes library is DRM-free.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You certainly can.

In iTunes, you can choose where your music library is stored:

```
ITunes->Preferences->Advanced->ITunes...location
```

If you want multiple iTunes accessing the library, it can get complicated. If other music players just use the folder structure, it should just work.

Extra scripts and config options can be set up so that iTunes uses a small local library if the network drive is not mounted, etc.

Comment: Thanks; will this significantly slow down playing tracks? (I assume it will, at the least, slow down the *loading* of tracks.)

Comment: Not significant. Songs are only a few megabytes.